# Company npm registries wont allow me to install cucumber

Tags: node.js, npm, cucumber, npm-install, .npmrc

I am trying to install cucumber-cypress package from npm. Problem is that we have company registers in npmrc.

Now when try to install cucumber-cypress `npm install --save-dev cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` package.
I get `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@latest is not in the npm registry.`

But when i switch registry to to `registry=https://registry.npmjs.org` i get 404 on some company package on this commnad `npm install --save-dev cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`

What should I do? Can i have two registers at the same time?

.npmrc

```
@somecompanystuff:registry=https:somecompanystuff
registry=https://somecopanystuff
```

and then i tried to add

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Comment: Can you share your `.npmrc`?

Comment: @Mureinik Actually I cant but i will try to rewrite so i can show it.